# Vue.js 2: set a prop value via http.get before the component is mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to get data from my server to populate a prop or data in vuejs.

Basically I need to pass the data as a parameter of my component.

```
    data() {
        return {
            recursos_data : [
                    { id: 'a', title: 'Room A' },
                    { id: 'b', title: 'Room B', eventColor: 'green' },
                    { id: 'c', title: 'Room C', eventColor: 'orange' },
                    { id: 'd', title: 'Room D', eventColor: 'red' }
                ],
            meus_recursos: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        getResources: function() {
            var self = this;
            Vue.http.get('/admin/getResources').then((response) => {
                _.forEach(response.data.resources,function(item){
                    self.meus_recursos.push(item);
                });
                console.log(self.meus_recursos);
                return self.meus_recursos;
            });
        },
    },
    mounted() {
        const cal = $(this.$el),
            self = this;

        self.getResources();

        cal.fullCalendar({
            header: this.header,
            defaultView: this.defaultView,
            editable: this.editable,
            selectable: this.selectable,
            selectHelper: this.selectHelper,
            aspectRatio: 2,
            slotDuration: '00:10:00',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            eventSources: self.eventSources,
            events: self.events,
            resources: self.recursos_data,
            fixedWeekCount: false,
            firstDay: 1
         });
     }
```

I need to get the data from the url but I don't know how to make it work.
I've tried computed, props, and method, but they don't work...

I need to get the data from the value returned from my server instead of from the variable **recursos_data**. How can one achieve this in vuejs?

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: @BertEvans I'am getting the data from a variable in which I've printed the data. Instead, I need to get this data from the http.get request. I've created a method to get the data. I am calling the method to get the values inside `mounted`, it prints the correct data in console.log command, but it doesn't sets the data in my component when I change `resources: self.recursos_data` to `resources: self.meus_recursos`. I need the data to be loaded before it is mounted.

Comment: Why can't you set the data using the `created` event? That's done before the mounted event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect your issue is some interaction between `fullCalendar` and your asynchronous method. You want to initialize `fullCalendar` after your data is returned.

How about returning the promise from your `getResources` method?

```
methods: {
    getResources: function() {
        var self = this;
        return Vue.http.get('/admin/getResources').then((response) => {
            _.forEach(response.data.resources,function(item){
                self.meus_recursos.push(item);
            });
        });
    },
},

mounted() {
    const cal = $(this.$el),
        self = this;

    self.getResources().then(() => {
        cal.fullCalendar({
            header: this.header,
            defaultView: this.defaultView,
            editable: this.editable,
            selectable: this.selectable,
            selectHelper: this.selectHelper,
            aspectRatio: 2,
            slotDuration: '00:10:00',
            timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
            eventSources: self.eventSources,
            events: self.events,
            resources: self.meus_recursos,
            fixedWeekCount: false,
            firstDay: 1
         });
    });
 }
```

Or, you could call `fullCalendar` right afterwards in `getResources`.

```
getResources: function() {
    var self = this;
    return Vue.http.get('/admin/getResources')
        .then((response) => {
            _.forEach(response.data.resources,function(item){
                self.meus_recursos.push(item);
        })
        .then(() => {
            $(this.$el).fullCalendar({
                header: this.header,
                defaultView: this.defaultView,
                editable: this.editable,
                selectable: this.selectable,
                selectHelper: this.selectHelper,
                aspectRatio: 2,
                slotDuration: '00:10:00',
                timeFormat: 'HH:mm',
                eventSources: self.eventSources,
                events: self.events,
                resources: self.meus_recursos,
                fixedWeekCount: false,
                firstDay: 1
             });
        })
    });
}
```

Alternatively you could not even mount the component until you retrieve the data.

Comment: I've ended up using the first solution, which worked as expected, giving the result I want. Thanks @bert-evans =)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: **you can't**.

You need to switch your mindset. Every component is reactive and should display itself accordingly to it's model. You can't "stop" the component while downloading your data from the server. I see 2 solutions in your this situation:

1. Handle "data not ready" state by displaying some throbber or just empty list. It doesn't matter if you are changing data internaly or changing props from the parent component. You can add a flag like `dataReady` to data and set it to true after your ajax has finished. In your template you will have some if statement using this flag to display the throbber or data.
2. Control it from its parent component and display the component one only after the data is ready.

No other ways.